# How do you uninstall a library when pip uninstall is not working?

Tags: python, uninstallation

Trying to uninstall the pdfquery library. Getting the following message:

```
pip uninstall pdfquery
Found existing installation: pdfquery 0.4.3
Uninstalling pdfquery-0.4.3:
  Would remove:
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfquery-0.4.3.dist-info/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfquery/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

I press "y" and enter but I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop. I tried several time to no avail. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Do you get an error, or any output at all, after pressing `y`?

Comment: I get nothing. It is running but nothing happens. I let it run for about 20 minutes but nothing.

Comment: Have you tried with elevated privileges ?

Comment: It seems as if "pip uninstall pdfquery -y" worked. Now to figure out why the new package won't install properly.